# Бесконечная анимация иконок с помощью JQuery

Tags: jquery

Задача такая: иконки должны увеличиваться поочередно, а после этого уменьшаться и так по кругу. Написал такой код этой самой анимации, правда работает это все только один раз. Как это можно реализовать? Анимация не обязательно должна быть бесконечной, хотя бы 5-10 итераций.
.icon1-7 имеют position:absolute.

```js
function iconTransform() {
  for (var j = 1; j < 10; j++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".icon1").animate({
        width: "18%",
        left: "-0.8%",
        top: "-10.8%",
      }, 500);
    }, 500);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".icon2").animate({
        width: "18%",
        left: "26.8%",
        top: "-11%",
      }, 500);
    }, 1000);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".icon3").animate({
        width: "18%",
        top: "-11%",
        right: "27.5%",
      }, 500);
    }, 1500);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".icon4").animate({
        width: "18%",
        top: "-11%",
        right: "0.8%",
      }, 500);
    }, 2000);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".icon5").animate({
        width: "18%",
        top: "25.5%",
        left: "40.9%",
      }, 500);
    }, 2500);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".icon6").animate({
        width: "18%",
        left: "27%",
        bottom: "10%",
      }, 500);
    }, 3000);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".icon7").animate({
        width: "18%",
        left: "54.7%",
        bottom: "9.6%",
      }, 500);
    }, 3500);

    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".icon1").animate({
        width: "17%",
        left: "-0.4%",
        top: "-10.2%",
      }, 500);
    }, 4000);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".icon2").animate({
        width: "17%",
        left: "27.5%",
        top: "-10.2%",
      }, 500);
    }, 4000);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".icon3").animate({
        width: "17%",
        right: "27.5%",
        top: "-10.2%",
      }, 500);
    }, 4000);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".icon4").animate({
        width: "17%",
        right: "0.4%",
        top: "-10.2%",
      }, 500);
    }, 4000);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".icon5").animate({
        width: "17%",
        left: "41.4%",
        top: "27%",
      }, 500);
    }, 4000);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".icon6").animate({
        width: "17%",
        left: "27.6%",
        bottom: "10%",
      }, 500);
    }, 4000);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".icon7").animate({
        width: "17%",
        left: "55%",
        bottom: "10%",
      }, 500);
    }, 4000);
  }
}
window.onload = iconTransform();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="benefits">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="title">
      <p>Почему именно мы?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="schedule">
      <div class="branches">
        --КОД SVG ВЕТОК--
      </div>

      <div class="icon1">
        --КОД SVG ИКОНКИ--
      </div>
      <div class="icon2">
        --КОД SVG ИКОНКИ--
      </div>
      <div class="icon3">
        --КОД SVG ИКОНКИ--
      </div>
      <div class="icon4">
        --КОД SVG ИКОНКИ--
      </div>
      <div class="icon5">
        --КОД SVG ИКОНКИ--
      </div>
      <div class="icon6">
        --КОД SVG ИКОНКИ--
      </div>
      <div class="icon7">
        --КОД SVG ИКОНКИ--
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[image]

Comment: для этого `css animation` существует, что бы не городить такое количество `setTimeout()`

Comment: Бесконечный цикл? `while (true) {` ? `for (;;) {`?

Comment: @Friendly 33 добавьте полный код с иконками, вёрсткой. Чтобы люди могли конкретно ответить, а не ограничиваться общими направлениями, куда вам нужно двигаться.

Comment: Совсем забыл за css animation,получилось сделать бесконечную анимацию,правда из-за отсутствия возможности добавления интервалов между повторениями ,иконки изменяются не совсем в нужном порядке и уменьшаются по отдельности,но спасибо,Air.

Comment: Вешал эти циклы,страница виснет и на этом конец