# Не корректно работает цикл

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Нужно, чтобы по клику на кнопку запускалась функция, которая увеличивает каждый блок(первый через 500мс, второй через секунду и т.д.), после увеличения всех блоков, все они одновременно должны уменьшиться до начальных размеров. Так же, все это должно повторяться несколько раз, 10, к примеру. Проблема состоит в том, что по запуску цикла, он проходит не все содержимое по одному разу, после чего должен делать это по новой, а начинает выполнять каждую строку по 10 раз, после чего переходит на следующую, выполняет ее 10 раз и так далее. В результате цикл,по сути, работает всего один раз.
Не знаю что еще можно попробовать, это нужно для реализации анимирования иконок: [Бесконечная анимация иконок с помощью JQuery](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/784241/%D0%91%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-jquery), пока так и не разобрался и реализовал через css animation, но возможности этой технологии не позволяют реализовать нужное в полной мере.
[image]
HTML:

```js
$('.buttons').click(function transform() {
  debugger
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('div.element1').css('padding', '80px');
    }, 500);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('div.element2').css('padding', '80px');
    }, 1000);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('div.element3').css('padding', '80px');
    }, 1500);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('div.element4').css('padding', '80px');
    }, 2000);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('div.element5').css('padding', '80px');
    }, 2500);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('div.element6').css('padding', '80px');
    }, 3000);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('div.element7').css('padding', '80px');
    }, 3500);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('div.element1').css('padding', '70px');
      $('div.element2').css('padding', '70px');
      $('div.element3').css('padding', '70px');
      $('div.element4').css('padding', '70px');
      $('div.element5').css('padding', '70px');
      $('div.element6').css('padding', '70px');
      $('div.element7').css('padding', '70px');
    }, 4000);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="schema">
  <div class="element1">1</div>
  <div class="element2">2</div>
  <div class="element3">3</div>
  <div class="element4">4</div>
  <div class="element5">5</div>
  <div class="element6">6</div>
  <div class="element7">7</div>
  <input type="button" class="buttons">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('.buttons').click(function() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (let j = 1; j <= 7; j++) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('div.element' + j).css('padding', '20px');
      }, 500 * j + (4000 * i));
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('div.schema div').css('padding', '10px');
    }, 4000 * (i + 1));
  }
});
```

```css
div.schema div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: lightgreen;
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br/>
<div class="schema">
  <div class="element1">1</div>
  <div class="element2">2</div>
  <div class="element3">3</div>
  <div class="element4">4</div>
  <div class="element5">5</div>
  <div class="element6">6</div>
  <div class="element7">7</div>
  <input type="button" class="buttons" value="Click">
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но все работает так же, как и у меня, то есть один раз то, что надо, но каждую строку по 10 раз крутит, если верить дебаггеру.

Comment: @Friendly33 Верьте не дебаггеру, а своим глазам. Нажмите кнопку "Выполнить код" в ответе.

Comment: Прошу прощения, моя ошибка была. Криво код копировал к себе в файл и не сразу понял, почему по кнопке "Выполнить код" все работает, а у меня нет. Спасибо, вам, большое!

Comment: @Friendly33 На здоровье. Успехов!